# update youtube live stream privacy status

Tags: scala, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm trying to update the privacy status of a LiveBroadcast in scala (using the java jdk). This is my workflow:

Create a LiveBroadcast with `private` privacy status

```
val snippet = new LiveBroadcastSnippet()
    .setTitle(title)
    .setScheduledStartTime(YouTubeDateTime.now())
    .setChannelId(channel.getId)

val status = new LiveBroadcastStatus()
  .setPrivacyStatus("private")

val broadcast = new LiveBroadcast()
  .setKind("youtube#liveBroadcast")
  .setSnippet(snippet)
  .setStatus(status)

val request = youtube.liveBroadcasts()
  .insert("snippet,status,contentDetails", broadcast)

request.execute
```

Transition the LiveBroadcast to `testing` (iff the bound LiveStream is active)

```
val request = youtube.liveBroadcasts
    .transition(lifeCycleStatus.toString, broadcast.getId, "status")

request.execute
```

Once happy with the stream, set the LiveBroadcast privacy to `public`

```
val status = new LiveBroadcastStatus().setPrivacyStatus("public")

broadcast.setStatus(status)

val request = youtube.liveBroadcasts.update("status", broadcast)

request.execute()
```

The last part does not work, instead returns a 400 response:

```
400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "youtube.part",
    "location" : "part",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
    "message" : "{0}",
    "reason" : "unexpectedPart"
  } ],
  "message" : "{0}"
}
```

Doing the same request [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/update) works, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I think you should also add `id` parameter in your LiveBroadcast request. It's the `ID` that YouTube assigns to uniquely identify the broadcast.

You may want to follow the guidelines on how to create and manage a live broadcast as discussed in [Life of a Broadcast](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/life-of-a-broadcast) wherein it was also mentioned that in processing the API response when setting up your broadcast:

> Your code should extract and store the `id` from that resource as you will need that value to identify the broadcast in future API requests. (You can also identify the video resource that corresponds to the liveBroadcast resource using the same `ID`.)

In addition to that, encountered error `400 Bad Request` with the specified detail `unexpectedPart`, as described from the common requests errors in [YouTube Data API - Errors](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors), means that:

> The request's part parameter specifies an unexpected value.